# how to keep icon in first column after reordering columns in in listview (detail view)?

Tags: listview, detailview

in list view control ( in detail view) after changing first Column display index (reorder) icon will move by first column. how to keep icon in first column after reordering? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is not very good way but because no one answer it, I thinked there is no better way. 
the way is easy in Reorder event first save new order then cancel it by

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

then delete columns and create them again but in new order.

I'll wait and if any better way did not come out.I'll accept it as answer.tanks